# How to load an url for a quiz app in android java?

Tags: java, android, url

I recently started a quiz app and i find a good site where i can make quizes with images, multiple responses and at the begining dsplays the score.

I don't know where is my error because with ggoogle.com works but with my quiz no.

This is the link that i want to load    surveyanyplace.com/s/pozitiemers

my class:

```
public class ChestionareA extends MainActivity2A {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView web;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chestionare_a);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://surveyanyplace.com/s/pozitiemers/");
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
  {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
}
```

Comment: Could it be some sort of connection timeout or how long the page takes to load? For me at least it took a _relatively_ long time to load the background image and what not. Check into it.

Comment: @user2152480 try the below.

Comment: @Raghunandan, what did u choose for minsdk and target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also added this is manifest  android:hardwareAccelerated="true". Not sure if it helps.

The below code worked for me. Try this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView wv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    wv.setWebViewClient(new MyOwnWebViewClient());
    wv.loadUrl("http://surveyanyplace.com/s/pozitiemers/");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
class MyOwnWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("http://surveyanyplace.com/s/pozitiemers/");
        return true;
    }
 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/wv"></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Resulting snap shot

[image]

Comment: I didn't add the hardwareAcceleration because my minsdk is 8 and target also 8. I saw that it works for android 3.0 and bigger. WIthout adding this in the manifest didn't work.I've try the code, i've added the internet permission but nothing shows.

Comment: Dear Raghunandan, I've tryed with a lot of Emulators, but my image don't fit like in your picture. Basically I copy-paste the code but the image doesn't fit.

Comment: The above was tested on samsung galaxy s3 which 4.7 inches i guess. You can set the scroll if it does not fit. set scroll for webview